# can't upload DataFrame with NaN with DolphinDB python api

Tags: python, database, dolphindb

While I was trying to upload some data to dolphindb server using python api, I found that dolphindb server will refuse to accept it and throw an exception if my dataframe contains null values. The following code could reproduce this.

```py
import dolphindb as ddb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["a", np.NaN]})
sess = ddb.Session()
sess.connect('localhost', 9921)
sess.upload({"t", df})
sess.run("1")
```

The error msg is as follows

```
 <Server Exception> in upload: Failed to read response header from the socket with IO error type 1
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good. Tested working fine. Please double check if you connect to the server properly or If the session is timed out. Otherwise, it could be a feature that had not been implemented at the time of question being raised.